# Postgres grant privileges issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have to create one database[myDB] and one custom schema[mySchema] not the public one.

Where did I go wrong:

I created 3 users: user_admin, user_rw, user_ro, which will be given access alter.

Now, I login with my super user: postgres [I am using postgres 11 on GCP] through cloud shell.

Created the my database: myDB, I went into myDB. And i fired below commands for all 3 users access.

```
# for admin user
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE myDB TO user-admin;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA mySchema TO user-admin ;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA mySchema TO user-admin ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-admin ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-admin ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-admin ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mySchema GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO user-admin;

# for read write user
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE myDB TO user-rw;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw ;
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw ;
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mySchema GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON TABLES TO user-rw;


# for read only user 
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE myDB TO user-ro;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA mySchema TO user-ro ;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-ro ;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-ro ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-ro ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mySchema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO user-ro;
```

Till this point i did not have any issue.

I created the table in mySchema with the help of user-admin, this would work like this in future as well.

And rest two users will use just for read and another for read write.

The problem is I can not able to see the created table from other users included postgres, user-rw, user-ro but only owner which was user-admin is having access to do all the operations like create and drop.

Also, after creating the table from admin user, when i rerun below command, it gives me permission denied.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw ;
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw ;
```

VS

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
   GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw ;
```

first option gives privileges to exist tables, the second option give you permission to exist ones and the new ones that i will be created in the future,

but he best approach is not apply this permissions direct to the user, create a group and grant the permissions there and assign the group to the user, the reason if you want to drop the user first u need to drop all the privileges created and after u can drop the user.

> Also, after creating the table from admin user, when i rerun below
>   command, it gives me permission denied.
>
> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO user-rw
>   ;

about this part make sure u are using the admin to give permission.

Comment: All the mentioned commands have been fired using sqlsuperuser[postgres], that is the reason I am not able to understand why exception is thrown.

Comment: first case when i created the all the priviledges for all the users no issues there but once I created the table via admin user the rest of the user did not able to see that created table, now what to do to make it visible to all the users? Second, if i try to give the those same privileges again command line responded Error permission denied, although i am using super user which is postgres [I used Google managed postgres instance]